# Euro or USD acceptance in Mauritius

Tags: money, exchange, mauritius

I note a booking with Booking.com informs that the room charged is given in Euro. Does that imply that Euro (and perhaps USD) is generally accepted in Mauritius?

Comment: Booking.com usually also mentions whether the room has to be/can be paid in said curency. Mostly they mention it in your curency (or the one they think you use) as a friendly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Travel-g293816-s601/Mauritius:Banks.And.Money.html friendly article for example:

> In Mauritius the currency of choice is the MUR, do not be taken in that Euros or dollars are widely accepted. They are not and if they are accepted by an establishment such as your hotel you will be given an unfavourable rate of exchange. This means you will have lost money.
>
> Do not change money in your home country unless you want to get a lower exchange rate. The rate in Mauritius is much better. When you arrive at the airport in Mauritius you will see a host of exchange bureaus at the arrival halls. Just bring your own currency and change it over there for a better deal.

Answer (score 0):

Namaste.
As i was informed at hotels and airport the usd and euro in conversion  bear huge loss. So get it exchanged outside of these two event places. Its better either carry  MUR  or any other currency like EUR /USD.
have safe journey.

Comment: It's not clear how this answer adds anything to the existing three years old accepted answer.